# why do we need to pass buffers to system calls in order to have information returned? Why can't system calls allocate the buffer internally?

Tags: files, memory, system-calls, buffer

I'm reading TLPI, and in section 4.4:

> System calls don’t allocate memory for buffers that are used to return information to the caller. Instead, we must pass a pointer to a previously allocated memory buffer of the correct size. This contrasts with several library functions that do allocate memory buffers in order to return information to the caller.

Why does system call don't allocate memory for these cases? Is it a memory optimization which allows user to use existing buffers (rather than needlessly allocate new memory)? Are there other reasons?

Comment: How would you tell the system call _where_ you want the memory allocated? For example, you may want the memory to be allocated after or before, or at some specific distance from, some other buffer or whatever other location in memory. Or, you may want the call to write at an offset into an already allocated buffer.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of developers forget that `malloc()` is not a system call; it's a C library function.  Actual memory allocation is done with the [`brk`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) system call which behaves very differently.

Put simply the program has just one block of allocated RAM for data which `malloc()` will request to be extended **if it needs to** using the `brk()`.  But `malloc` can just as easily re-use a buffer after it was released with `free()`.  When buffers are freed, they are not (necessarily) returned to the OS as [they are often in the middle of the heap](http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/how-do-malloc-free-work-in-c/#free).

Now to your question: Why can't system calls allocate the buffer internally?

The kernel does not know how your program uses its data block.  It cannot assume you are using the C library or `malloc` so it can't interact with that data structure; it doesn't know for sure what data structure you are using to allocate buffers.  This means it cannot allocate a buffer than `free()` can release.

In theory it could allocate entire pages of RAM in unused address spaces but then freeing them would require an entirely new system call with a very significant overhead; this would be much more costly than `free()` which typically does not result in a system call.  This would also be very wasteful as buffers are much smaller than whole pages.

Finally it's worth understanding that in many cases the program may already want the data in a particular place.  There's simply no need to force the code to copy the data and free the page when it could just ask the system call to write the data directly where it wants it.

Comment: not just that `malloc()` can reuse buffers after they've been released, but it can ask the OS for a much bigger chunk of memory once, and then deal out several allocations from that.

Answer (score 2):

When you want the kernel to allocate memory, you call `mmap()`.  When you call `mmap()`, you have to choose what flags you want.  Do you want your allocation to be `PROT_EXEC`, `MAP_HUGE_2MB`, or `MAP_LOCKED`?  Do you want it to be allocated at a specific address (`MAP_FIXED`)?

So it is simpler to keep allocation separate.  It means we do not need a parameter for these flags in every system call.

De-allocating memory using the kernel requires making another system call: `munmap()`.

It is faster to *de*-allocate, if you did not allocate using the kernel directly.  `free()` is not a system call, so it is faster than `munmap()`.

There are also historical reasons.  The original UNIX kernel could not allocate and free arbitrary pages of memory.  You could call `brk()`, which increased the size of heap memory.  You could not ask the kernel to free chunks of memory inside the heap.